# Animation Nodes Error When Checking off Add-on

Tags: animation-nodes

I have installed Animation Nodes from animation_nodes_v2_1_windows_py37.zip in Blender 2.80. Installation seemed fine. When I check off 'Node: Animaton Nodes' in the list off Add-ons, I get an error message [image]

Answer (score 0):

I saw on the Animation Node Github page the answer is to download VC_redist.x64.exe from Microsoft. Sorry, I should have read that before posting - hopefully this will help other people searching for the same issue.